# A cloud based notepad - must be stable

Tags: windows, linux, website, web

I need to make a few lists and such for a trip to India that I need on the web to access from any computer from India. Now, here are my problems.

- If I do it on paper, I'll lose it by the time I get on the flight.
- I can't use anything that uses Flash or Silverlight because internet connections in India are slow, and, I doubt I can find a computer with Flash or Silverlight properly installed.
- I can't use anything that's experimental (otherwise, I would use [wrttn](http://wrttn.in/) which seems really good, but, if they decide to clear their database, that's bad for me)
- I would not like to use a flash drive, or desktop application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for a desktop application that will sync with the cloud, or a web application? If you are using a web application, this should be posted on [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). If you do want a web app, respond to this comment and I will migrate it, otherwise, please edit it to make it clear that you want a desktop application.

Comment: "because internet connections in India are slow, and, I doubt I can find a computer with Flash or Silverlight properly installed" Wow such sweeping generalizations!

Comment: Mayank: better safe than sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with Google Docs?

Alternately, email the lists to yourself with whatever webmail you use.

Third option, most smart phones (and not-so-smart phones) can do this.  You may not be taking a phone with you since you may not be able to connect to their cell network, however.  I know a lot of Americans have compatibility problems when they go abroad.  (Not saying you're American, just that they have problems.)

Comment: never thought of emailing it to my self, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/). It is very simple and stable. No need for anything like Flash, either. As far as I can see, it meets all of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) has not been suggested yet.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote)

> Evernote is a suite of software and services designed for notetaking and archiving available in a paid version or a more restricted, advertising-supported, "free" version. A "note" can be a piece of formattable text, a full webpage or webpage excerpt, a photograph, a voice memo, or a handwritten "ink" note. Notes can also have file attachments. Notes can then be sorted into folders, tagged, annotated, edited, given comments, and searched.

I use evernote for your exact reason. it is easy to capture information and store it for a later time

Comment: Evernote is a good choice. It's web based, and there are also app versions that will sync with your mobile devices.